# Handsontable Width and Height in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

I am trying to render my Handsontable display with the same width & height across each browser (IE, FF, Chrome) - I currently have the container's height and width set to 95% of it's parent container. This renders fine in Chrome and FF, however in IE the records get truncated and horizontal scrolling distorts the header - cell alignment.

```
#hot-container {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    overflow: auto; //adds scrolling to the table
}
```

If I define my height & width with a set `px` value, It displays just fine, however I need my table to scale. Is there any solution out there for this?

My final solution is to use a set `px` h/w when a user is using IE using an IE-only CSS shim. I thought of going with the conditional IF statement, but these do not work in our standard browser, IE 11 (conditions are not supported)

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    #hot-container {
         width: 800px;
         height: 500px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well if `#hot-container` is the only visible item on the screen, you can obviously go with the `position: absolute` trick!

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

#hot-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 5% /* since (100 - 95)%; 0 if you want it to fill full screen */
    bottom: 5% /* since (100 - 95)%; 0 if you want it to fill full screen */
}
```

Good luck, have fun!